# JSON ResponseSchemaValidation in Karate

Tags: karate

```
  "totalRows": 1,
  "colDefs": [
    {
  "entityAttributeId": "acctNm",
  "headerName": "Account Name",
  "field": "2",
  "entityPath": "",
  "entityId": "account"
},
{
  "entityAttributeId": "acctId",
  "headerName": "Account ID",
  "field": "1",
  "entityPath": "",
  "entityId": "account"
}
],
"rowData": [
{
  "1": "1939",
  "2": "Bay Pond Partners",
  "rowMeta": {
    "account": {
      "acctInstrumentId": "0025-1939",
      "acctId": "1939"
    }
  }
  }
]
}
```

I have following response from a filter query. As the filter should return only one value, that I am validating with this :
And match GetDataSet_Response contains {"totalRows": 1}

The filter is based on Acctid. Now, I need to validate acctID value and entire json schema. How can I do it in KARATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Schema you can define a

- The data type of values which you are expecting but don't know the exact values.
- Write an expected condition for your data.
- Define the variable of data or hardcode data which you already know.
- Ignore few data which don't bother.
- break down your JSON and create multiple logical schemas(From your JSON you can have a separate schema for "colDefs" and "rowData")

and many more options for complex validations.

I am not sure about your exact requirement, I have tried to create a schema that might suit your requirement.

```
{
  "colDefs": [
    {
      "entityAttributeId": "acctNm",
      "entityId": "account",
      "entityPath": "",
      "field": "2",
      "headerName": "Account Name"
    },
    {
      "entityAttributeId": "acctId",
      "entityId": "account",
      "entityPath": "",
      "field": "1",
      "headerName": "Account ID"
    }
  ],
  "rowData": [
    {
      "1": "#string",
      "2": "#string",
      "rowMeta": {
        "account": {
          "acctId": "#(acctID)",
          "acctInstrumentId": "#string"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "totalRows": 1
}
```

You can store schema in a JSON file / define it directly in your script and match it with your response

*assume we stored this schema in a file* `filterResponseSchema.json`

YourFilter.feature

```
* def acctID = "1939"
# call your filter request
* def myFilterSchema = read('filterResponseSchema.json')
* match response == myFilterSchema
```

**Note:**

i) make sure there is a variable name "acctID" before calling this schema so that karate will embed that value to you JSON schema.

ii) my assumption for your "colDefs" values will be always the same, so I hardcoded it.

[Karate documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation) covers a good amount of example for **Schema validation**

I suggest you read this for more insights.

Comment: I am a newbie in Karate. This schema looks perfectly fine but how can i use it?

Comment: you can keep it in a json fine/ define it in your feature and match it with your response

Comment: added a sample feature in the answer itself

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Can you please let me know from where or which tool (if used any) you used for creating this schema. It will help me next time.

Comment: Glad it worked :). I used JSON editor in eclipse and wrote it on my own based on your question. I don't there is any tool available for this.

Comment: btw you can refer karate documentation to get familiar with it.